# Locale in link_to doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### The goal

Make URLs like `/en-US/welcome/` automatically, without any manual prefix or something like this.

### The problem

Just don't work. There appears no locale in my URL.

### The scenario

My `application_controller.rb` already has the `default_url_options()` method:

```
def default_orl_options(options = {})
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

This is my `routes.rb`:

```
[...]

get "home/index"

root to: 'home#index'

get '/:locale' => 'home#index'

scope '/:locale' do
  resources :home
end

[...]
```

And finally, to show a link:

```
[...]

<%= link_to '', url_for('buy') %>

[...]
```

The result? `http://localhost:3000/buy/`. ***I just want `locale` prefixing the URL.***

By now, thanks!

Comment: What is this `'buy'` route? What happens if you write `<%= link_to 'link_text', home_path %>`?

Comment: @MarekLipka `No route matches {:controller=>"home", :action=>"show", :locale=>:"en-US"} missing required keys: [:id]`

Comment: So, what is this `'buy'` route?

Comment: It must be just a normal page. There's nothing about `buy` in `routes.rb`. Should I create something?

Comment: Give it a try. Something like `get '/:locale/buy'` should work.

Comment: Nothing, @MarekLipka. Unfortunately, no results - still the same.

Answer (score 0):

In newer apps the preferred format is:

`Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:locale]= I18n.locale`

### App Directions

- Create a file called `config/initializers/default_url_opts.rb`
- Add the the above example to the file and then restart the application.

Comment: Should I to put this on `application_controller.rb`? Within a method? If so, which one?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Normally I would create an initializer and throw it in there.

Comment: I'm very newb on Rails. Can you go on just a little further, please?

Comment: Thank you Jordon, but unfortunately without success again. The result is the same - no locale for URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue as you, despite following [Rails guidelines for this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#managing-the-locale-across-requests) (defining that `default_url_options` method in `ApplicationController` and the `I18n.locale` being set in a `before_action`).

My problem was that somebody had put a `default` argument in the scope in `routes.rb`, something like this:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|pt-br|es/, defaults: { locale: ''}
...
```

As [this question points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24712695/1290457) (read 'the possible problem'), the `defaults` there, despite the name, actually overrides that locale parameter. The result being that I was only getting localized links in `link_to` (that uses `url_for`) if I specifically specified the locale in it's arguments, something like `link_to(dashboard_path(locale: I18n.locale))`, which was exactly what setting `default_url_options` in the ApplicationController supposed to avoid me having to do.

Removing the `defaults` from the scope block in routes.rb was half the solution; the other half was this improved code in ApplicationController#default_url_options

```
  def default_url_options(options = {})

    { locale: I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale ? nil : I18n.locale }.merge(options)

  end
```

The source for this last one being [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8237800/1290457).