# Rails4: How to wrap an engine into a routing scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, spree

Is there a way to "wrap" an existing rails 4 routing from a rails engine into a routing scope like described here: [Rails routes with optional scope ":locale"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224245/rails-routes-with-optional-scope-locale) ?

I want to use the spree gem (https://github.com/spree/spree) and insert the current locale as the leftmost part of the path, like /en/products/t-shirt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it the same way:

```
Sandbox::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|fr/ do
    mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
  end
end
```

You'll need to do more work to tie this locale in to Spree's locale, but that's a good place to start.