# How to easily insert "m" paramater (mobile) in a rails website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobile, layout

I want to insert a URL parameter "m" which stands for "mobile" to all the URLs I have now. I don't consider other options at the moment such as addaptive design.

So how can I **easily and safely** insert "m" **without breaking** down the current functionality? Should I just add a section in routes.rb? If so, what should it look like?

"m" is optional, if it's ommited then a website should be displayed in a normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write some simple [Rack Middleware](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html).

Maybe something like this

```
class ParamSanity
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    request.params["m"] = stands_for_mobile
    status, headers, body = @app.call(env)

    [status, headers, body]
  end
end
```

Then in config/application.rb

```
config.middleware.use ParamSanity
```

Comment: that's a hack. isn't there a better, clean solution?

Comment: There are many other ways one could implement this, such as using a `before_action` in ApplicationController. Personally, I do not feel that using Rack middleware to globally add parameters is a hack. It's how Rails itself does it.

Comment: 1) can't it be done by adding a route or namespace in routes.rb instead? 2) how to do that via before_action, could you show me?

Comment: I am not aware of a way to add a parameter to all requests and responses by using routes. do use a `before_action`, define a method in `ApplicationController`, manually add the param (just like I'm doing above), and then use the before filter like so: `before_action :my_cool_method`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
scope "(:mobile)" do    
   ...your resources
end
```

Take a look at this question
[Rails routes with optional scope ":locale"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224245)

Comment: so it won't break anything?

Comment: No, it won't.
All your routes will be accessible in two ways:
`/posts/12`
`/m/posts/12`
Just in latter case you will have additional parameter `params[:mobile]`.