# default_url_options is not overriding route defaults

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to add locale to all routes, instead of updating all `*_path` and `*_url` calls I am trying to add a `default_url_options` method to my application controller, this is the method I'm using

```
def default_url_options
  { locale: (I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale ? nil : I18n.locale.to_sym) }
end
```

This is my routes file:

```
locales = I18n.available_locales - [:en]
scope '(:locale)', locale: /#{locales.join('|')}/, defaults: { locale: I18n.default_locale } do
  get   '/login', to: 'sessions#new', as: :login
  root to: 'home#index'
  match '*a', to: '#missing_action', via: :all, as: nil
end
```

`login_url` will render `http://localhost:3000/login` which is not what I want.

If I remove the `defaults:` from my route scope I get the correct urls

1. `http://localhost:3000/login` when `:locale` is my default locale
2. `http://localhost:3000/es/login` when `:locale` is my `:es`

I'm using `Rails 5.1.3`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using namespaces?

```
namespace :locale, defaults: { locale: I18n.default_locale } do
```

Also just found this, looks like these guys have solved it already: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8237800/3753556

Comment: This answer you linked is what I'm using, also, namespace would not work as it adds a superclass to all controllers